# How to generate a list of field items using the field item name programmatically in Drupal 7?

Tags: entities

I need a way to generate a simple list of all the items in a particular field. The field name is field_portfolio_description, and I'm looking to simply loop through the results and output each item into an unordered list. For example:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to do this programmatically without using a module like Views? I would also like to display the data in page.tpl.php not node.tpl.php. I tried checking out some Drupal functions like field_info_field but they weren't much help.

Update:

I've been working with the following function in my template.php file:

```
function blocks_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $node = $vars['node'];
  if ($node->type == 'portfolio') {
    $vars['description'] = $node->field_portfolio_description[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
  }
}
```

However a quick var_dump($description) where I'm trying to access the data brings up null. Am I on the right track?

edit: fixed typo

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty much on the right track. Try something like:

```
function blocks_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $node = $vars['node'];
  if ($node->type == 'portfolio') {
    $portfolios = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_portfolio_description');
    $items = array();
    foreach ($portfolios as $folio) {
      $items['data'] = $folio['value'];
    }
    $vars['description'] = theme('item_list', array('items' => $items));
  }
}
```

Adding stuff to nodes like this is maybe better in [hook_node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) in a custom Module. Because you're altering the node's content before its shown (and its adding derived content to the node, not just changing some markup at the theme layer).

**Code is untested and just Help. (but should mostly work)**

**Resources**

- [theme_item_list](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_item_list/7) function docs
- [field_get_items](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) function docs
- alternatively create a "Code Field" using [Display suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) to encapsulate this custom code field to a view_mode (aka, magic). [See this tutorial on youtube on DS and custom fields](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvFP16PJt4c).

Comment: Spooky - I just wrote an answer with exactly the same code (even down to the `foreach` element being called `$folio`) and this popped up :)

Comment: Thank's for the input tenken (and Clive), I appreciate you both taking the time. The code looks good to be but unfortunately it didn't seem to work, var_dump($description); where I'm trying to output the data still brings up NULL. 

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious. I'll keep playing around with this, but if anyone else has ideas I'm all ears.

Comment: @BradC Are you still trying to print the description in `page.tpl.php`? If so you need to put the code in `blocks_preprocess_page()` instead, and change the first line to `$node = menu_get_object();` Then clear the caches and try again

Comment: @clive yes I'm trying to print the values in the page template. I tried your suggestions and I'm still getting NULL on $description.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, other answers for this question were posted [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11817/d7-theme-field-items-of-a-list-text-input-as-ul/65390#65390).

Alternatively, instead of editing your templates or the preprocess template.php file, you can use the tiny module [Text Formatter](http://drupal.org/project/textformatter) which allows you to set the display of your fields to list items.